# Trying to create a script to change settings on Plantronics hub

Tags: windows, powershell, settings

I’m new to the IT industry but keen to learn.

Wanted to ask if anyone could point me in the right direction when trying to create a Powershell script to change settings within a computer app called plantronics hub.

Just need a better insight to what commands I need to use and functions. Just so that instead of going to a users machine every time  and changing the settings I can just run a script and let it do it for me.

Comment: Perhaps investigate what if any APIs are supported by the devices, E.g https://developer.plantronics.com/softphone-integration-api-overview

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can look at.  Look through the program files to see if there's any kind of command line utility for this sort of thing.  Obviously, documentation is another good place to look.  If available, you can also call their support and simply ask.  Keep in mind they may have already considered this scenario, and may have other suggestions.

Try and figure out how the application stores its settings, Registry, XML, ini file etc...?  PowerShell can work with any of these, but you need to answer this question before knowing what direction to go it.

If the settings are in the registry I'd start looking under HKLM:/ & HKCU:\Software\Plantronics. Settings and/or configuration files may be in the program files folder or under the user profile app data folders.

A few techniques:

1. Export the registry, make a configuration change, export the registry again to a different file. Compare the 2 files via some file comparison tool, like BeyondCompare or WinMerge.  This might help you find anything that changed after you made the change.
2. Use [procmon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) .  If you filter it properly you can determine which files the application is touching either on start or when you make a configuration change.  ProcMon can also help identify which registry keys and values are being looked at.

Note: If the settings are consistent between stations you may be able to copy the config. This could be as simple as a file copy or importing a registry file.